# Getting the IP of systems connected to my local Express server

Tags: node.js, express

I created a simple Web Application using Express. When my Express Node server is running, I can visit the application from devices, other than my system, which are connected to the same WiFi network as me.
How do I know which device visited my website? Can I get the Private IP address, assigned by my router, of the users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ip` property of the `request` object Like below.

Here's how you can send the IP for a request.

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send(req.ip));

app.listen(80, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 80!'))
```

Comment: I had one doubt is it possible to get actual user IP who is using this rest api. For  example I had one api i.e., 
  https://xxx/Alpha/api/kriyoAdmin/login I want to know at where this api call happens ? as per ur code it returns xx of api. But I want actual IP like 192.168. so and so

Comment: Sorry, made the edit. I mistakenly written `hostname` in my answer.

Comment: It is returning response as ::1. So how it would be IP Address of system?

Comment: `::1` is `localhost` in ipv6

Comment: How can I get ipv4 address?

Answer (score 0):

I used this code to get ipv4 address and physical address of a system. Hope this helps .

```
var os = require('os');
var on=os.networkInterfaces();
var o=JSON.stringify(on);
var obj = JSON.parse(o); // this is how you parse a string into JSON 
var n=JSON.stringify(obj['Wi-Fi']); //use "Wi-Fi" for windows system and "wlp3s0" for LINUX systems
var nn=JSON.parse(n); 
var n2=JSON.stringify(nn[0].mac);
var n3=JSON.stringify(nn[1].address);
console.log("Physical Address: " +n2);
console.log("IP Address : ",n3);
```